# How to Create joint in Box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i am developing a game, in this game i have Chain. chains One side is Static and another is dynamic. and chain is moving in ccTouchMove.as chain move,dynamic part get exten and looks like a curve. chain length  is Fix. So how can i set fix Length and curve in it.

Refer me Which Joint i have to Use. i am trying RopeJoint but i get error in 
                b2RopeJointDef  jd;

can some one send me sample code.

Comment: b2RopeJointDef jd;
 jd.bodyA=anchorBody; //define bodies
 jd.bodyB=body;
 jd.localAnchorA = b2Vec2(0,0); //define anchors
 jd.localAnchorB = b2Vec2(0,0);
// jd.maxLength= (body->GetPosition() - anchorBody->GetPosition()).Length(); //define max length of joint = current distance between bodies
 world->CreateJoint(&jd); //create joint

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use rope joint and use code like this..

b2RopeJointDef rp;
rp.bodyA=dragonFlyAnchor; //define bodies
rp.bodyB=foodItemBody;
rp.localAnchorA = b2Vec2(0,0); //define anchors
rp.localAnchorB = b2Vec2(0,0);
rp.maxLength=((foodItemBody->GetPosition()) - dragonFlyAnchor->GetPosition() ).Length(); //define max length of joint = current distance between bodies
world->CreateJoint(&rp); //create joint
```